# undefined local variable or method `newrelic_ignore_enduser'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic

New Relic documentation says:
[*To prevent page load timing (sometimes referred to as real user monitoring or RUM) for all actions in a controller, add a call like this to the controller class:
`newrelic_ignore_enduser`*](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ignoring-specific-transactions#page-load-timing-rum)

I added a call to `newrelic_ignore_enduser` as follows, and got the error `undefined local variable or method 'newrelic_ignore_enduser'`.

**books_controller.rb**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    require 'newrelic_rpm'
    ...
    def show
        newrelic_ignore_enduser
    end
    ...
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.9.9.275'
```

**Question:** What do I need to do (`require` something perhaps?) in order to be able to call this method?

---

**Update**

Oops! I had previously only included `newrelic_rpm` in `Gemfile` in the `production` group. I have now added it to `group :development, :production do` and that helped. The second thing I had to do is call the method as `newrelic_ignore_enduser only: :show` from the `class` level (as shown in the selected answer), not from within the action as I initial tried. Note that ideally I would prefer to call this method from within the action, and based on a condition.

Comment: From the page you linked to: If you get a `NoMethodError` when trying to use `newrelic_ignore` from within a Rails controller or Sinatra application, make sure that `newrelic_rpm` has been required before you try to call `newrelic_ignore` inside of your class definition.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `require 'newrelic_rpm'` but unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: Actually, it did help - I just had to combo it up with the answer and comment by @aguardientico. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `newrelic_ignore_enduser` as follows

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    newrelic_ignore_enduser only: :show
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not help - it still gives the same error.

Comment: do you add `newrelic_rpm` gem just for production? or also for dev?

Comment: Oh, wow, great question! It turns out that I did have it just for `production`. Oops - my oversight! I have now added it do development, and your answer is correct! Though too bad I cannot call this method from inside an action and have it depend on a condition, e.g. `newrelic_ignore_enduser if some_condition` - I have a particular condition in the `show` action on which I don't want the Javascript injected, but otherwise it would not be a problem.